# Use common functions in Android

Tags: android

I have a set of 3 functions which i uses in 3 activity classes. Instead of putting the 3 methods in each of the 3 classes, how can i write the 3 methods only once and then call these methods in all other classes...

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.icon:
            settingBoard();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void settingBoard() {
        Log.i(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Preparing settings page..");
        /*
         * progressDialog.setMessage("Preparing settings page.....");
         * progressDialog.show();
         */
        Intent lma = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(lma, 3);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: can you show the method startActivityForResult() ... does it use private members/fields of a class?

Comment: startActivityForResult() calls the SettingsActivity class which runs on its own........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write an abstract Activity subclass that contains these three functions. Then derive your three Activity classes from the abstract class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can i have an example please on how to derive 3 activity classes from abstract class

Comment: For each of your three activities, just use `extends BaseActivity` instead of `extends Activity` (after you define `abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity { ... }` with your three common functions).

Comment: Hi Ted....what happens when a activity extends ListActivity ....we cannot extend the BaseActivity then

Comment: Do all three activities extend BaseActivity? If so, have BaseActivity extend ListActivity. If not, then you'll have to use something like the composition approach suggested by @kgiannakakis. If necessary, you can pass an instance of the client activity to the constructor of the utility class (so the utility class will have an Activity instance for things like startActivityForResult).

Comment: I have 4 activity classes....2 of which extends Acticity and other 2 extends ListActivity. I could use BaseActivity for 2 classes as sujjested by you.....what should i do for activity classes that extends ListActivity..... am not familiar with composition approach or utilities.

Comment: Create a new class that has these three functions. It will not compile, because functions like startActivityForResult and onOptionsItemSelected require an Activity (and `super` in this case will not be one). The solution is to: 1) define an Activity member field; 2) define a constructor that accepts an Activity, and initialize the member field; and 3) use the member field everywhere you need an Activity instance. Then create one of these classes in each of your real Activity classes, passing `this` to the constructor. Then delegate to the utility class any calls to the first two methods.

Answer (score 2):

I can propose two choices:

- **Inheritance**: Create a base class (MyActivity) that implement these methods and override it to create your activities. The advantage is that the methods can use protected properties.
- **Composition**: Create a utility class that implement these methods. Make an object of this class a member of the activities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the assumption that `R` and `Log` are static objects that you're referencing. If thats the case then you could simply place these functions in a class file, and include this class in all classes you wish to use these functions in. Then you'd be able to refer to them as `ClassNameOfYourChoice.functionName()`.

Comment: The calls `getMenuInflater()` and `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` will get in the way of this approach. (The first might be eliminated by using the static `View.inflate` method.)

Comment: I didn't know what exactly those functions were. But that makes complete sense now.